# Are pre-save signals handled before the clean method in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-signals

I could not find a reference to it. The question is honestly pretty self-explanatory. In Django forms, such as admin forms, the clean method is automatically called before saving. My question is, if I have a method as a pre-save signal, which one will execute first?

Comment: `pre_save` signals are executed when `.save()` is called. So, any kind of validation will take place before the signal gets triggered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the django docs: "This is sent at the beginning of a model’s save() method." You can find this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-save and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders

The clean method works as a validation which means it always runs before the save method, you can find more information about this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

You can also validate this on the Django admin code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1545